# Expand IndentedTree to specific element

Tags: nvd3.js

Is there a way to programatically expand an nvd3 IndentedTree as in http://nvd3.org/examples/indentedtree.html to a specific element of the tree and add a class "active" to this element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

NVD3 uses the "values" property of a tree node to mark expanded elements, and "_values" for collapsed elements.

So, if you want to expand/collapse a tree or part of it, you move the content from _values to values or vice versa. After that, call chart.update() to get a redraw.

In addition, to add a class "active" to the  element containing the tree node, I used the "classes" callback of the columns array. The callback runs on the child element of the table data element:

```
classes: function(d) {
  if (d.isSelected) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("class", "active");
  }
}
```

"isSelected" is a property I added to the current node.